# php to compare two lapses of time

Tags: php, datetime, math, compare, timelapse

I'm looking for a way to compare two lapses of time.

If the second lapse or part of it is in the first one -> return false.
Although, if the first one or a part of it is in the second one -> return false too.

I feel like I didn't have to skive math lessons...

I got

```
// first lapse
$a = strtotime('2016/05/04 22:50');
$b = strtotime('2016/05/20 22:15');
// second lapse
$y = strtotime('2016-05-12 12:00');
$z = strtotime('2016-05-20 10:00');

if (($y >= $a && $y <= $b) || ($z >= $a && $z <= $b)
|| ($a >= $y && $a <= $z) || ($b >= $y && $b <= $z)) 
    return false;
```

But it's quiet confuse in my brain. I'm not sure it does what it supposes to do.
Thank you.

**Edit**

I found my question was duplicated [with this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

Comment: if you're not sure if does what it's supposed to, how will we know?

Comment: Because it's a sharing knowledge forum. I just need some help... And I want to learn.

Comment: Computers are not magic, and we're not psychic. If you cannot describe the output you want, and/or the process to get it then there's no point in even attempting to write code.

Comment: It's because I said I was skiving math lessons ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if $a <= $b and $y <= $z, count

```
min($b, $z) - max($a, $y)

if < 0 - no overlap    
   = 0 - common boundary point   
   > 0 - overlap
```

Comment: if > 0 not overlay and if > 0 overlay ? It looks pretty serious but I don't understand it well. May you add some explanations, please ?

Comment: Thanks. typo. Simply draw on paper and you'll understand - the maximum of  left edges of the segments is right than the minimum of right

Comment: @AdrienLeber do you understand the solution ?

Comment: Yes, I tested this solution. It seems to work great. Thank you for your help and thank you not telling me "blabla... computers are not magic... blabla... go back to school... blabla..."

Comment: Good luck! Glad to help